# How to apply multiplicative price seasonality to bond prices in quantlib?

Tags: fixed-income, python, quantlib, inflation

Can someone please give a brief or any link which explains how to apply multiplicative price seasonality to inflation linked bonds in Quantlib using python modules. Have gone through most of the example but couldn't find anything on the same.